How Anderson Darling hypothesis test is set up?
I'd like to know what is the hypothesis test behind Anderson Darling test. I know that H0 is for data follows the distribution and H1 is for data doesn't follow the distribution. But how is it written mathematically? I suppose it uses the A2 value, like H0: $A^2 = 0$ and H1: $A^2 \gtrless 0$. Is this correct?

What is A2 -.- ?

...it has a Wikipedia page...

A2 is the Anderson Darling statistic.

The Wikipedia page doesn't answer the question

$$H_0: F_X =F_0$$
$$
H_a: F_X \ne F_0
$$
The null hypothesis is that the distribution function (CDF), $F_X$, equals some assumed distribution function, $F_0$.
The alternative hypothesis is that the null is false, that the distribution function, $F_X$, is not equal to the assumed distribution function, $F_0$.

Could you elaborate more about the test statistic and how the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis is obtained? (I would love to see a permutation based version of the test).

@Ggjj11 I encourage you to post a question asking exactly that.
